# zip created by archive manager is smaller than one created by zip on command line

Tags: archive, compression, zip

I am creating a zip archive of one file, in 3 different ways:

- `zip -1` (least compression) --> 33.8kB
- `zip -9` (most compression) --> 32.3kB
- archive manager (zip option) --> 26.1kB

Why is there such a big difference?

Related: I'm trying to automatically zip files in Python using the `zipfile` module, and its performance is comparable to that of `zip`, but I want its performance to be that of archive manager. However, I can find no documentation on what archive manager does exactly. It claims to use 'zip' but clearly the compression is better...

Comment: Is it an option for you to use another compression tool/method, for example `xz`, which usually provides better compression than `zip`?

Comment: You may check actual file type with `file archive.zip`. You can try to open archive with `file-roller archive.zip` and see its *Properties* (*Type* and *Compression ratio*).

Comment: @N0rbert it stated that p7zip compression was used. Strangely enough if I try to select .7z in file-roller, the file gets even smaller, and the properties (as in: which algorithm was used with which parameters) are identical!